# What causes the output of this noise texture to be different from the example?

Tags: texturing, materials, shaders

So, I have a noise texture.  However (and I have just the output of the noise texture painted on the mesh) I seem to have a much different pattern from the example:

[image]

His is a lot more.. "roundy" while mine is a lot more "wavy."

Don't get me wrong, I'm pretty sure I can come up with other ways of generating the texture that he has (for example, an image input) but I would be grateful if someone could help me understand WHY there is a difference here, because it might help me increase the predictability of the shader stuff.

By the way: this tutorial is nine months old, I believe he is using 2.81 and I am using 2.83.

Answer (score 1):

He's using the *Object* output socket of his *Texture Coordinate* whereas you're using the *UV* output socket.

Comment: Also, if you still notice a stretching after plugging the object coordinates, apply your object transforms with CTRL + A > Scale

Comment: oh yes you're right it also might be a problem